# How do I set up Amazon S3 notification to receive notifications when certain events happen in your bucket using aws-cdk in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

How do I set up Amazon S3 notification to receive notifications when certain events happen in your bucket using AWS-CDK in python? When I use the code below, I am able to set up the subscription. But when a file gets uploaded to S3, it doesn't send me an email. When I manually update the access policy in the SNS console it works, but I don't know how to implement that in my CDK. I have also attached the SNS access policy that I am trying to achieve but I am not getting that. Here is my CDK snippet:

```py
        #SNS

        sf_topic = aws_sns.Topic(
            self, "MyTopic",
            display_name="My Topic"
        )

        email=aws_sns_subscriptions.EmailSubscription("example@email.com")
        sf_topic.add_subscription(subscription=email)

        notification = aws_s3_notifications.SnsDestination(sf_topic)

        sf_bucket.add_event_notification(aws_s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, notification)
```

```
{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Id": "example-ID",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "s3-event-notifier",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
     "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
   },
   "Action": [
    "SNS:Publish"
   ],
   "Resource": "<UPDATE-YOUR-SNS-ARN-HERE>",
   "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": {          
      "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:<UPDATE-YOUR-BUCKET-NAME-HERE>"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an iam.PolicyStatement and attach it to your SNS topic.

```
policyStatement = _iam.PolicyStatement(
    resources=[sf_topic.topic_arn],
    actions=[
        "sns:Publish"
    ],
    effect=_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    conditions={"ArnLike": {"aws:SourceArn": sf_bucket.bucket_arn}}
)

sf_topic.add_to_resource_policy(policyStatement)
```